# Use AD authenication in azure App Services

Tags: azure, security, azure-web-app-service

We have easily sent up our AD with Azure SQL which now we can login and run queries, etc... with SSMS. Now we would like to set our apps in Azure App Services to run as an AD user. This would be to mimic IIS apps using an application pool that's is running as an AD user. I have not found a clear blog or step by step guide on how to do this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
This is specifically to be able to connect to the database using AD Credentials and not using SQL Credentials.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement more? It is not possible to change the process identity. However, you can use Easy Auth to setup AD Authentication and then impersonate the credentials to achieve your requirement.

Comment: please see the update

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory authentication for SQL Database or SQL Data Warehouse supports the following methods of connecting to a database using Azure AD identities( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication)):

- Using integrated Windows authentication
- Using an Azure AD principal name and a password
- Using Application token authentication

And the scenario you mentioned is not support. We can create an application in Azure AD and using the token authentication for this scenario. More detail about Azure AD authentication, you can refer the link below:

[Configure and manage Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL Database or SQL Data Warehouse- Azure AD token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token)

In addition, if you have any idea or feedback about Azure SQL database, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database).